# Sqlite Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' when set to x86, Could not find type 'xxx' when set to x64?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sqlite, dll

Trying to use Sqlite in my VB.net app, thought it would be simple so I installed it via the NuGet package manager.  Now i've lost a week to this hate to admit, I just can't make it work for the life of me.

When I set my build to x86, it say's it can't load SQLite.Interop.dll, when I set my build to x64 it can't find one of my custom controls within my project.  I tried some solutions from other SO questions but none of them worked for me.

Can someone help me out here?  It's getting pretty frustrating.  Apparently their NuGet package is completely broken for me, so I downloaded just System.Data.SQLite.dll from the vendors website, referenced it in my project, set to Copy Always, and changed my build from AnyCPU to x86 (to match the DLL).  Which results in an exception stating the referenced assembly cannot be found.

Comment: Your last sentence gives the answer: "the referenced assembly cannot be found.". 'I think the vendor dll needs some dependencies which you didn't download or didn't copy to your target directory.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen  That is only when I do it manually, what about NuGet?  Is that just totally broken for this package?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I never used SQLLite.

Comment: What is nuget package id you use?

Answer (score 0):

you also need to download the SQLite package from here http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

make sure you download abd install the x86 version even if your running x64.